# Change of Colour on second animated circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created an animated circle with a timer. I need to change the colour of the second circle.

How can I do that as I can't figure it out.

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEkWY/)

I am attaching the colour of the animated arch with the following CSS:

**CSS:**

```
.timer > #slice > .pie {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    width:160px; /* 170 - (2 * border width) */
    height:160px; /* 170 - (2 * border width) */
    clip:rect(0em,0.5em,1em,0em);
    -moz-border-radius:0.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius:0.5em; 
    border-radius:0.5em; 
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('div.timer'+instance).html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"'+(percent > 50?' class="gt50"':'')+'><div class="pie"></div>'+(percent > 50?'<div class="pie fill"></div>':'')+'</div>');
```

Comment: Do you mean the color of the **outer edge**? looks like changing the `blue` (in the code you posted) to the color you want can solve it? Or you just want to change the color of the second circle (keep the first unchanged)?

Comment: @KingKing I want to keep the first one blue and do the second animated circle a different colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not really understand the jQuery code (which is fairly complicated), but to change the color for the second circle, you just need to add this style to the current one:

```
.timer.xs4all > #slice > .pie {
  border-color:green;
}
```

It's because the second circle is wrapped in a different `div` which has classes `timer xs4all`, while the first one is wrapped in a `div` having classes `timer upc`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEkWY/1/)